# percent occupied for each month

Tags: percentages

An air plane recorded how many of its 180 seats were occupied in past five months   january-130 february-121 march-168 april-179 may-178 how many percent occupied for each month?

Comment: What are you stuck on exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Divide the number of seats occupied by the total number of seats, and then multiply by $100\%$. In other words, for each month, separately, calculate $$\dfrac{\text{number of seats occupied}}{180 \text{ total seats}} \times 100\%$$